# How to errase an object in an arrary?

Tags: pull

I need to erase an especific object inside a collection in an arrary, I want to use the method $pull or the .pull but its'n working right now

I use the method $pull but is not working!

Comment: which language you want?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working in JavaScript, my mentor says that's a cascade erase but I didn't find anything like that I can use

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.pop();

const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(0, 1);
```

you can check these two links.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp